# external sorting: multiway merge

Tags: algorithm

In multiway merge The task is to find the smallest element out of k elements

Solution: priority queues

Idea: Take the smallest elements from the first k runs, store them into main memory in a heap tree.

Then repeatedly output the smallest element from the heap. The smallest element is replaced with the next element from the run from which it came.

When finished with the first set of runs, do the same with the next set of runs.

Assume my main memory of size ( M )less than k, how we can sort the elements, in other words,how multi way merge algorithm merge works if memory size M is less than K

For example if my M = 3 and i have following

Tape1: 8 9 10 
Tape2: 11 12 13
Tape3: 14 15 16
Tape4: 4 5 6

My question how muliway merge will work because we will read 8, 11, 14 and build priority queue, we place 8 to output tape and then forward Tape1, i am not getting when Tape4 is read and how we will compare with already written to output tape?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work. You must choose a `k` small enough for available memory.

In this case, you could do a 3-way merge of the first 3 tapes, then a 2-way merge between the result of that and the one remaining tape. Or you could do 3 2-way merges (two pairs of tapes, then combine the results), which is simpler to implement but does more tape access.

In theory you could abandon the priority queue. Then you wouldn't need to store `k` elements in memory, but you would frequently need to look at the next element on all `k` tapes in order to find the smallest.